# How to simplify boolean expression with not and or?

Tags: python, algorithm, boolean-logic

I have the following boolean expression:

```
not (start_date > b or s > end_date)
```

how to simplify it?

```
def is_date_in_items(end_date, start_date, items):
    b, s = _get_biggest_and_smallest_date(items)
    return not (start_date > b or s > end_date)
```

Comment: `start_date < b and s < end_date`

Comment: @deceze Techincally, `<=` should be more correct, I think.

Comment: `~(A or B) = ~A and ~B`

Comment: Assuming `b` <= `s`, `return start_date <= b <= s <= end_date` seems logical too.

Comment: See Wikpedia for more info: [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
not (start_date > b or s > end_date)

// is equivalent to 
not(start_date > b) and not(s > end_date)

// which is equivalent to 
start_data <= b and s <= end_date
```

This comes from [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) which states that:

```
¬(P OR Q) <=> (¬P) AND (¬Q)
```

Comment: Logic to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a bit shorter:

```
start_date <= b and s <=end_date
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I almost did. Blindly parroting the existing comments without adding anything substantial over it (like the other answer did) only seems like you are piggybacking off of it for points.

Comment: @COLDSPEED - not my intention at all, I'm new here, will take into consideration in future answers. Thank you for your comment.